# How to debug pip install <package name>

Tags: debugging, pip, installation, setup.py, pdb

If I want to debug the setup.py file of my package packagename getting installed via "pip install packagename" , is there a way to do so? I have tried downloading the source, adding set_trace() in setup.py and run:

```
    pip install .
```

However, as soon I get pdb() prompt, the install fails with error:

```
processing /Users/skauser/python-ibmdb/IBM_DB/ibm_db
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    > /private/var/folders/b6/pmddncpn77550p8_g9kkx9f40000gp/T/pip-req-build-_fg8s5a2/setup.py(31)<module>()
    -> machine_bits =  8 * struct.calcsize("P")
    (Pdb)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/b6/pmddncpn77550p8_g9kkx9f40000gp/T/pip-req-build-_fg8s5a2/setup.py", line 31, in <module>
        machine_bits =  8 * struct.calcsize("P")
      File "/private/var/folders/b6/pmddncpn77550p8_g9kkx9f40000gp/T/pip-req-build-_fg8s5a2/setup.py", line 31, in <module>
        machine_bits =  8 * struct.calcsize("P")
      File "/Library/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/bdb.py", line 88, in trace_dispatch
        return self.dispatch_line(frame)
      File "/Library/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/bdb.py", line 113, in dispatch_line
        if self.quitting: raise BdbQuit
    bdb.BdbQuit

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/b6/pmddncpn77550p8_g9kkx9f40000gp/T/pip-req-build-_fg8s5a2/
```

Although I can debug the source via: python setup.py build, the behavior that I want to debug is applicable when installed through pip.

Comment: Come on, people. In about any other environment a package manager just saves a log file for detailed inspection after an installation error. Or at least gives you a verbose run-mode. Do you really need to attach a debugger for this?

Comment: @aef, Yes.  The problem with "print debugging" is that it is slow, cumbersome, and almost useless compared to proper debugging.  What we _should_ care about with software development is knowing what the CPU is doing.  Instead, we have an entire generation absolutely terrified of a CPU, let alone knowing what it does.  So we are stuck with this mess of build systems building build systems to output libraries that build libraries.  None of which work, all of which break all the time.  It's horrible.  We need _more_ debuggers, not less.  And yes, I know this is a Wendy's.

Answer (score 3):

Pip is a python program. You can see it's content with `cat $(which pip)`. Then you can copy it to a new file in your project's directory. For example, here is how it looks like for me:

File `mypip.py`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys
from pip._internal.cli.main import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

Then **you can add a breakpoint with pdb or use PyCharm** as mentioned in the answer from Igor Yudnikov.

For reference, this is how it to looks like in my Pycharm
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Oh! Just found a solution, its pretty easy. What is pip? It's a plain python file, which is I think somehow bound to run via python, and under the hood system makes something like

```
python pip install ...
```

so, at first we need to know where is pip

```
which pip
```

says

```
/Users/me/PycharmProjects/etlscripts/venv/bin/pip
```

So, we may go to Pycharm, create config like

[image: Pycharm run config]

then you'll be able to catch your exception. Cheers.

Comment: Does not work for me, as pip can't find its own modules anymore (pip 21.0)

Answer (score 0):

remember you can (should) run pip as `python -m pip` so you can do `python -m pdb -m pip install xxx`